# Flip NSButton's image upside down

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift3, transform, cgaffinetransform

I have a very simply macOS app (written in Swift using Xcode 8.2.1). In my main UI there is an NSButton with a custom image (it represents a playing card - like in Poker). When I click that button I'd like its image to be drawn rotated by 180 degrees (flipped upside down).

I'm new to affine transforms but I thought this might work (it doesn't).

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
  var transform = sender.layer?.affineTransform()
  transform = transform?.rotated(by:  180.0 * (CGFloat.pi / 180))
  sender.layer?.setAffineTransform(transform!)
}
```

The card is rotated properly but it is drawn in a new location.

What is the right way to rotate a button's image by 180 degrees while keeping its position in its parent static?

Comment: Have you added constraints to your Button ?

Comment: There are no constraints and auto-layout is disabled.

Comment: Check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate `NSImage` or `NSButton` image I wrote an extension for `NSImage` using Swift 3.

You can pass to the function:

- Rotation degree let's say 180 degrees.
- The desired image to rotate.

Here is the way to call it:

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: NSButton) {

     sender.image = NSImage().imageRotatedByDegrees(rotationDegree: 180,
forImage: sender.image!)

}
```

And your extension:

```
extension NSImage {

     func imageRotatedByDegrees(rotationDegree degrees:CGFloat,forImage
image:NSImage) -> NSImage {

         // calculate the bounds for the rotated image
         var imageBounds = NSRect(origin: NSZeroPoint, size: image.size)

         let boundsPath : NSBezierPath = NSBezierPath(rect: imageBounds)

         var transform : NSAffineTransform = NSAffineTransform()

         transform.rotate(byDegrees: degrees)
         boundsPath.transform(using: transform as AffineTransform)

         let rotatedBounds : NSRect = NSRect(origin: NSZeroPoint, size:
boundsPath.bounds.size)

         let rotatedImage = NSImage(size: rotatedBounds.size)

         // center the image within the rotated bounds

         imageBounds.origin.x = NSMidX(rotatedBounds) - (NSWidth
(imageBounds) / 2); imageBounds.origin.y = NSMidY(rotatedBounds) -
(NSHeight (imageBounds) / 2)

         // set up the rotation transform
         transform = NSAffineTransform()

         transform.translateX(by: +(NSWidth(rotatedBounds) / 2), yBy:
+(NSHeight(rotatedBounds) / 2))

         transform.rotate(byDegrees: degrees)

         transform.translateX(by: -(NSWidth(rotatedBounds) / 2), yBy:
-(NSHeight(rotatedBounds) / 2))

         // draw the original image, rotated, into the new image
         rotatedImage.lockFocus()
         transform.concat()

         image.draw(in: imageBounds, from: NSZeroRect, operation:
NSCompositeCopy, fraction: 1.0)

         rotatedImage.unlockFocus()

         return rotatedImage

     }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Aaoli! The only issue is when you set the rotation degrees to something like 15. Each successive rotation makes the image smaller and smaller.

Comment: @RobertJoseph I'll check it out :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a translation transform to translate the center to 0,0 and then rotate, and then translate back so the center is where you want.  Something like:

```
 transform = transform?
     .translatedBy(x: -self.center.x, y: -self.center.y)
     .rotated(by:  180.0 * (CGFloat.pi / 180))
     .translatedBy(x: self.center.x, y: self.center.y)
```

Comment: Thank you. What does self refer to in your example? Would that be `sender` in my example? Also, NSView does not have a center property.

Comment: @RobertJoseph it's probably your sender.layer :)

Comment: @AaoIi Thanks but CALayer doesn't have a center property either (at least not on macOS).

Comment: @RobertJoseph then it's probably the sender which is the button.

Comment: @AaoIi `sender` (`NSButton`) doesn't have a center property either. On iOS UIView has a center property. That doesn't exist on NSView or CALayer on macOS.

Comment: @RobertJoseph I see I'll take a look at it and get back to you

Comment: Here is my view controller [code](https://gist.github.com/rmangino/b34f528e970d21b76fa8ded6ed178a62). The image for the button was set in the storyboard.

Comment: @RobertJoseph I see that you are calculating the center so did it work or you are having an issue?

Comment: @AaoIi No, it doesn't work. The button image disappears until I resize the window (and even then the image is still in its original orientation).